# Ant Tomcat: Failed to create task or type "list"

Tags: linux, spring-mvc, tomcat, ant

I am using [**Spring official docs**](http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html) to understand the Spring Basic Application and Environment set up on Linux using Ant.

### Softwares and system configurations:

- **OS:**  Linux/Ubuntu
- **JRE:** 1.8.0_51-b16
- **Ant Version:** 1.9.3
- **IDE:** Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)

### Project directory structure:

[image]

Everything goes fine till end of **[Section 1.3](http://docs.spring.io/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part1.html#step1.3)** where I can start the tomcat server and execute `ant`, `ant deploy` successfully and I have the desired output as follows:

[image]

[image]

But when I am trying to execute `ant list` - the build fails.

```
Buildfile: /home/sandeep/MyDocs/workspace/springapp/build.xml

list:

BUILD FAILED
/home/sandeep/MyDocs/workspace/springapp/build.xml:113: Problem: failed to create task or type list
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.
```

Here is the `list` target in my `build.xml`:

```
<target name="list" description="List Tomcat applications">
    <list url="${tomcat.manager.url}"
        username="${tomcat.manager.username}"
        password="${tomcat.manager.password}"/>
</target>
```

What am I doing wrong here? Here is a link to my **[entire build.xml](https://pastebin.com/vWaNyuV6)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the article you linked to, it shows how to add the `<list>` task:

```xml
<taskdef name="list" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ListTask">
    <classpath refid="catalina-ant-classpath"/>
</taskdef>
```

Add the above line to your `build.xml`.

Comment: Yes. You are right. I missed to add that. Here's the link to final [**build.xml**](https://gist.github.com/sndpchatterjee07/cdbaa589e13b1f30a3f9) which helps execute `ant list` successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I think task list is unknown to ant. There is no task named list defined by [ant](https://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html). To start tomcat I did something like --

```
    <exec executable="${tomcat.home}/bin/tomcat5.exe" >
        <arg value="start"/>
        <env key="JAVA_OPTS"
             value="-Xint -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=${hotswap.port},server=y,suspend=n"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```